# Minimum Hard Drive Size for SharePoint 2010 and SQL Server 2008 dev machine

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I plan to have VS 2010 on my local box, and I'm building a VM with SP 2010 and SQL Server 2008.
What hard drive size should I shoot for on the VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to create a fixed-sized(for better performance) hard drive which is at least 50GB big.

I've built SP2010 development machine the other day and after installation of VS2010, SP2010, SQL Server 2008, Office 2010, Sharepoint Designer and some other tools I had about 15-20 GB of empty space which is quite good to have for other stuff.

UPDATE: If you have a chance, take a look at [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228652). In first chapter author describes in details how to set up a perfect sharepoint2010 development machine.